# Transfer Session cookie from one Request to another in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, dotnet-httpclient, system.net.httpwebrequest

I have 3 different Servers.

```
On Server A I have a webpage pageA.aspx
On Server B I have a webpage pageFrame.aspx
On Server C I have a Web API controller controllerC.cs
On Server A I have another page pageB.aspx
```

pageA.aspx and pageB.aspx are different pages on the same website.

pageFrame.aspx is embedded in pageA.aspx as an IFRAME.

pageA.aspx has both the standard ASP.NET authentication and Session cookies, along with other cookies.

pageFrame.aspx picks up these cookies and makes an ajax call to ControllerC.cs and is able to pass these cookies along in the POST Request.

ControllerC.cs now needs to make a POST Request back to Server A by calling pageB.aspx but it needs to pass along the cookies it received in the ajax call from pageFrame.aspx. By doing this it can reach the same session that pageA.aspx was in.

Now pageB.aspx does some processing and replies to the POST request with a ticket(guid). This ticket is then sent back from ControllerC.cs as part of the response to the ajax call to pageFrame.aspx. pageFrame.aspx then submits this ticket to pageA.aspx as a response to the originally request.

PageA.aspx now simply submits back to its web server and can pick up from the session whatever pageB.aspx has placed in the session during its processing.

Now my question is how do i transfer the cookies from pageFrame.aspx's ajax post request in ControllerC.cs to the request it is making to pageB.aspx?

I have been trying to use HttpClient and trying to add the cookies from one request to another but they seem to be in two different namespaces and when i do make a post the cookies aren't picked up and sent. Does anyone know how I can write the code in ControllerC.cs to pick up the cookies in the request made to it from pageFrame.aspx and pass it to the new request it is making to pageB.aspx?

I look forward to and appreciate your help.

Thank you,
Gmat